# numerical radius of operators

Tags: functional-analysis

In this question $E$ stands for a Hilbert space over $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.

For $(T_1,...,T_d) \in \mathcal{L}(E)^d$, is the following inequalities true ?
$$\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}\left\|\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^dT_k^*T_k \right\|^{1/2}\leq \omega(T_1,\cdots,T_d) ?,$$
where 
 $$\omega(T_1,...,T_d)=\displaystyle\sup_{\|x\|=1}\bigg(\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^d|\langle T_kx\;|\;x\rangle|^2\bigg)^{1/2}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the operators $T_k$ are all non-zero and skew-symmetric over $\mathbb R$, then $\omega()$ is zero, and the desired inequality does not hold.